# How do i execute a particular step in StepDefinition class

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured

I'm new to Cucumber and RestAssured framework.

In my class `Stepdefinition` is having 3 steps methods. It supposed to run only 3rd step in `Stepdefinition` file. Is it possible to run only one step?

I follow standard maven project structure, i.e. step definitions in `src/test/java` and feature file in `src/test/resources`.

Please let me know if you need any more information on this regard.

Comment: Cant you just create a scenario with only that step in the feature file and run the feature file with a tag?

Comment: My stepDefinition need 3 steps, but my intention is that is there any chance to run particular step among all.

Comment: Thanks , I got the answer